# Demonstrate the solutions of a linear system of equations with A matrix, while B being A's generalized inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, generalized-inverse

I am looking to demonstrate that the *X* solutions matrix to a linear compatible system of equations (A|*b*) and *B* being a generalized inverse of A; such that *ABA=A*, can be expressed as:

*X* = *B · b + (B · A -$I_m$)* · $\begin{bmatrix}k_1 \\ ... \\ k_2\end{bmatrix}$

being $k_1, ..., k_2$ *K* values.

I am thinking of using *PAQ-reduction* to prove this. However, I haven't got quite clear the ideas on how to start, or whether which demonstration.